# Como criar PDF a partir do .jasper

Tags: jsf, ireport, jasper

Criei um relatório no iReports e gerei o .jasper, mas não faço nem idéia de como gerar o PDF, já tentei vários tutoriais e nada funciona, para criar o pdf. O que eu preciso é gerar o PDF e pegar o caminho do arquivo criado para setar dentro de um campo no banco de dados. Eu tava tentando utilizar esse método, não retorna erro algum, mas também não cria o arquivo.

```
   public void imprimirRelatorio() throws IOException, ParseException {

        HashMap parametros = new HashMap();
        parametros.put("ID_EDITAL", 28);

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                "inline; filename=\"arquivo.pdf\"");
        try {
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource dsColecao = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista, false);
            JasperPrint impressoraJasper = JasperFillManager.fillReport("d:/Edital.jasper", parametros, dsColecao);
            ServletOutputStream streamDeSaida = response.getOutputStream();
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(impressoraJasper,
                    streamDeSaida);
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        facesContext.responseComplete();    
    }
}
```

Onde faço a chamada do método:

```
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit"
                        actionListener="#{editalBean.inserirEdital}" update="growl"
                        process="@this" />
```

Ao chamar o método inserirEdital do editalBean ele chama o método imprimirRelatorio().

A lista que passo no dataSource no caso é uma lista de Editais. Alguém podia me ajudar? Dar um rumo? Estou totalmente perdido.

Comment: Pelo amor de Deus, preciso muito disso, dou todos os meus pontos se possível pra quem me ajudar. :(((

Comment: Você quer escrever o pdf de saida do Jasper direto no disco? Ou quer gravar no banco em uma coluna do tipo blob? Ou quer escrever o pdf na resposta dessa requisição? O código na pergunta faz o terceiro.

Comment: Eu achei esse código na internet, não sei nem muito que faz pra se sincero :(((. Mas bem, eu preciso escrever o pdf no disco (dentro da pasta web-content por exemplo), e então pegar o caminho desse pdf para salvar no banco de dados em um campo do tipo String.

Comment: Então você deve usar o `JasperExportManager.exportToPdfFile` passando o nome/caminho do arquivo. Ou usar o `JasperExportManager.exportToPdfStream` passando um `FileOutputStream`. Se você quiser gravar direto no banco, sem gerar arquivo, sugiro usar o `ByteArrayOutputStream` com o `exportToPdfStream` e usar o `toString`.

Comment: Assim que eu chegar na faculdade de novo eu vou testar e dou um feedback. Jaja to voltando pra lá.

Comment: Mas eu só muto esse método, e mantenho todo o resto? E quanto ao meu JRBeanCollectionDataSource ta certo?

Comment: Sim, o `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` é usado para passar um `DataSource` que seu relatório espera, a única mudança é o método que ira chamar na exportação. É mesmo necessário guardar o pdf no banco (isso gera grandes impactos)? Porque não gera ele sobre demanda?

Comment: Gerar sob demanda é uma alternativa também. Como eu faria para gerar sob demanda?

Comment: Quando o usuário solicitar, através de um botão. Você executaria o código da pergunta.

Comment: Exatamente do jeito que está? Porque eu tentei assim e não funcionou =(

Comment: Está usando ajax? Esse código não funciona com ajax.

Comment: Vou editar o código mostrando o código que chamo ele.

Comment: Para fazer um `p:commandButton` fazer submit, use o atributo: `ajax="false"`.

Comment: Ele ta retornando esse erro agora: javax.servlet.ServletException: Method not found: managedBean.EditalBean@4ad878b3.inserirEdital() Mas eu tenho o método inserirEdital.

Comment: Será que já não estava retornando erro antes e não tinha nenhuma mensagem no console (do servidor)? O `inserirEdital` esta declarado como: `public void inserirEdital()`? Não tem nenhum argumento?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20719/discussion-between-joao-neto-and-wakim).